# react-native-datetimepicker Change Text Color

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, datetime, datetimepicker

**Issue**

I need to change the color of the text displayed in the picker for react-native-datetimepicker as I have a very dark background and the text is extremely hard to see on it.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried passing in color: 'white' as a style to the DateTimePicker component and I've also tried passing in the itemStyle prop to the DateTimePicker component as that is how you change text styles on react-native's Picker component.  Neither have worked.

***Does anyone know how to change the text style in react-native-datetimepicker?***

**Example**

[image: Example]

Comment: Did you try textColor ?

Comment: @Oleg I tried adding a style prop textColor and I also tried adding textColor directly as a prop to  the DateTimePicker component and neither worked.  Where do you suggest I try adding in textColor?

Comment: Have you tried `isDarkModeEnabled=true`?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker/issues/119

Answer (score 4):

If you are using expo, you must go to node_modules/react-native-date-picker/style.js folder and use this:

```
dateText: {
    color: '#fff'
},
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the property [textColor](https://github.com/react-native-community/datetimepicker#textColor-optional-ios-only) available:

```
<DateTimePicker 
...
textColor="white" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass in hex format. If you pass in `#FFFFFF`, the text color should change but there's an issue though. It only changes the color after a user interaction. The current date is always set to black. I don't think it can be modified though. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker, in this article it states that the `UIDatePicker` is not customizable.